# Is there Text Data Type available in Golang?

Tags: string, go, text, types

I am working with elasticsearch where I use the latest elasticsearch. The problem is that the latest elasticsearch uses text to replace string

https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

My question is, how can I convert string to text for my golang program?

Is there any Text data type in golang?

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any Text data type in golang?

No.

Use string.

Answer (score 1):

That article is about mapping types, not data types. It's about how ES processes JSON strings (as in "a string of bytes").

You still send and receive the same bytes when transmitting documents.